# Running docker image as a specific user in AKS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a docker image, **myimage**. I can run this image with a specific username (example: **engdata**) using docker run command as follows:

```
docker run -it -p 5108:5108 -u engdata myimage
```

When I deploy **myimage** to AKS, it runs as root. How do I tell it to run as user **engdata**?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod

Answer (score 1):

Your base image may have set the user id to 0. You can overwrite this if you know that other users exists by specify the user id in the Kubernetes example i provide. If you dont know this, simply add an user to you image build process:

```
FROM node:slim
RUN useradd engdata -u 10001 --create-home --user-group
COPY --chown=engdata . /home/engdata/app/
USER 10001
WORKDIR /home/somebody/app
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

Your Pod or Deployment manifest for Kubernetes:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 10001
```